# Why b.r is not visible while printing?

Tags: c, structure

I have this structure after scanning and printing p and q are printed while r is not printed can you please let me know why?

```
struct book
{
int p;
float q;
char r;
};

int main()
{
struct book b;
scanf("%d%f",&b.p,&b.q);
scanf("%c",&b.r);
printf("%d......%f.....%c",b.p,b.q,b.r);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %c",&b.r);` if you want a whitespace between the float input and the char input.

Comment: It is. You have to know how to enter it: http://ideone.com/DV1LFq

Comment: Why i add a space between float and char during scan it doesn't print anything why?

Comment: are p, q, and r initialized correctly?  int, float, and char have different "null"/non-initialized behaviors.  Could you include what the output looks like?

Comment: http://ideone.com/2RE2bi This is the input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :**

that's because `b.r` takes in the `\n` character entered at the end of the previous `scanf()` statement

```
scanf("%d%f",&b.p,&b.q);
```

---

**Solution :**

Avoid it by giving a space before `%c` in the `scanf()`

```
scanf(" %c",&b.r);
```

> **Why give a space ?**
>
> This would consume if there are any whitespaces (`' '` or `'\n'` or `'\0'`) present in the input stream

---

**Suggestion  :**

next time when you don't get any output when you print, try printing it's ascii value by casting it to `int`, that way you'd know what value the variable is taking and see it's corresponding character in [**ascii table**](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html).

```
printf("%d",(int) b.r);
```

for example, without making any changes to your code except this to your `printf` statement :

```
printf("%d......%f.....%d",b.p,b.q,(int)b.r);
```

you'd get

**input :**

```
2
2
```

**output :**

```
2.....2.....10
```

> **why the** `10`**?**
>
> because it's the ascii value of `\n` or the newline character

Comment: or it could be a space.  I was entering 1<space>1<space>1 for input, same problem.

Comment: @ebyrob i'm not able to get what you say...

Comment: You already answered it.  `' '` may be used as the separator.